# POM missing for dependency <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

Tags: maven, maven-3

When I try the below dependency I receive this warning - [WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:spring-ojb:jar:2.0-rc2 is missing, no dependency information available

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ojb</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-rc2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Can this cause any issues ? Why is there no pom for this dependency ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like spring-obj project became part of spring-modules project from Spring 2.0 RC4. Here is the spring module [announcement](http://www.springsource.org/node/343) page as well as a [discussion](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-30463.html) in spring community forum.

Based on how you want to use this feature, you may either want to take an older version of this (or its dependencies) or use the newer spring-module version.   You could also download the jar and manually install it to your local maven repository (`mvn install:install-file`)

Answer (score 1):

With the rc2 dependency, I didnt find the pom in my repository either. Looking at the [maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-ojb/2.0-m4), there I found version m4. Using the new dependency, I found the pom in my maven repository.

Comment: So is this just an oversight when the dependency was added, why would a dependency be added with a corresponding pom file ?

Comment: http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/inspect-pom/org/springframework/spring-ojb/2.0-rc2/spring-ojb-2.0-rc2.pom - with rc1 the pom was removed. But the site displays, the pom cant be found. Not sure why it was removed.